# Django-nonrel with Google App Engine: Missing AutoloadMiddelware class?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I just deployed a website using Google App Engine that I built using Django.  However, whenever I try to view my site live, I get a 500 error, and when I go into the App Engine dashboard and check the logs, I see the error:

```
"ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "autoload.middleware" does 
not define a "AutoloadMiddelware" class"
```

But this doesn't quite make sense as I checked the autoload folder in my project and inside, there is a middeware.py file that indeed defines an AutoloadMiddleware class as follows:

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings

# load all models.py to ensure signal handling installation or index loading
# of some apps 
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        import_module('%s.models' % (app))
    except ImportError:
        pass

class AutoloadMiddleware(object):
    """Empty because the import above already does everything for us"""
    pass
```

Is there something wrong with the import, perhaps?  Is it possible my deployment didn't upload the necessary django modules in addition to those in my project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add it to your settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: I checked the settings.py file and it turns out I made quite a goofy mistake here--I had mispelled AutoloadMiddleware as 'AutoloadMiddelware.'  Thanks for your help, if I hadn't double-checked my settings file I never would have noticed the spelling mistake...